# AutoCompleteTextView behaves differently in different versions of android

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, autocompletetextview

I am not clear whether this is an issue with different versions of Android, or different screen sizes, but I am getting some unpredictable behavior.

I am testing the UI of the dropdown of a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` on a `Nexus S` which is on `Android v4.1.2` and I am testing on a `Nexus 4` which is on `Android v4.2.1`.

When I begin to enter text into the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` it returns some results.  I have created a custom view which contains an `ImageView` to the left of a `TextView`.  When the a row is first displayed, the `ImageView` will have a certain height and width (image on left).

[image]
[image]

However once you scroll through the list of results and back up to that original row one, of two things happens.  Either the `ImageView` stays the same dimensions, or the dimensions of the `ImageView` will change (image on right).

This specific behavior, and the screenshots provided, are what is happening on the `Nexus 4`, but I cannot reproduce this issue on the `Nexus S`.

I am loading `Bitmaps` into `ImageViews` just like it is done in the developer training [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Here is the layout resource for the contact row:

**contact_entry2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contactPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        vandroid:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contact_pic_desc"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/contactInfo"
        style="@style/CheckedTextViewStyle" >
    </CheckedTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CheckedTextViewStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And RecipientsCursorAdapter is a grandchild class of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` (BaseContactsAdapter extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`):

**RecipientsCursorAdapter**

```
package com.sendit.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.sendit.Contact;
import com.sendit.R;
import com.sendit.util.ContactsUtils;
import com.sendit.util.ImageFetcher;

public class RecipientsCursorAdapter extends BaseContactsAdapter {

    private final String DEBUG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;

    public RecipientsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, Activity a, int flags, ImageFetcher imageFetcher) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, a, flags);
            mImageFetcher = imageFetcher;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_entry2, null);
            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.contactInfo = (CheckedTextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.contactInfo);
            holder.contactPic = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.contactPic);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.position = position;

        mCursor = getCursor();

        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        int contactId = mCursor.getInt(mCursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        if (mContactCache.get(contactId) == null) {
            String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String number = ContactsUtils.getPhoneNumber(mContext, contactId);
            mContactCache.put(contactId, new Contact(name, number));
        }

        Contact c = mContactCache.get(contactId);

        CharSequence contactInfo = getContactInfoSpan(c.getName(), c.getPhoneNumber());

        holder.contactInfo.setText(contactInfo);

        mImageFetcher.loadImage(contactId, holder.contactPic);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as what to look into?  Is this a screen resolution issue, or does the latest version of Android handle this situation differently than previous versions?

Comment: Its not issue . As per the version its compatible and the behaviors will get change. So As per that its changing. And also one more thing as per the Developers (Particular Manufactures) can change the default functionality of Autocomplete text view. according to that also it will get change. actually its not a issue. generation changes.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean @Rajesh.  Are you saying that different manufacturers of Nexus devices implement the stock android experience differently?

Comment: No ,,But the Android Os versions are getting change right,. So They may be have the update for that. and also the device size may get change.

Comment: I am hoping to get a more detailed answer as to why this kind of behavior if happening.  If in fact its due to the way Android v4.2.1 displays the dropdown, then what is the specific reason why this is happening.

Comment: Could you post some code? Specifically if you had to override any adapters (or list the adapter you used, if any), and also the XML layout for each "list" item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Andrew for the suggestions.  Here's how I fixed the image resizing issue.  I called the `ImageView` `setScaleType()` and `setLayoutParams()` methods when instantiating the `ViewHolder` references.

```
public class RecipientsCursorAdapter extends BaseContactsAdapter {

    private final String DEBUG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;
    private final Drawable mDefaultContactPic;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

    public RecipientsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, Activity a, int flags, ImageFetcher imageFetcher) {

        super(context, layout, c, from, to, a, flags);
        mImageFetcher = imageFetcher;
        mDefaultContactPic = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mDefaultContactPic.getIntrinsicWidth(), mDefaultContactPic.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_entry2, null);
            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.contactInfo = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactInfo);
            holder.contactPic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactPic);

            holder.contactPic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.contactPic.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.position = position;

        mCursor = getCursor();

        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        int contactId = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        /*...*/

        mImageFetcher.loadImage(contactId, holder.contactPic);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, glad if that helped. It looks like some properties of the ImageView are set when created or first filled with an image, and then they are not modified/reset when filled with a different image, later, after being recycled.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a wild guess it's to do with the View recycling.... when you go down the list then back up, your original image is shown inside a recycled view that had it's width/height set in the initial load of a differently sized image.

If so, it's probably a bug in the version of Android. Either way, you'll have to deal with it.

Maybe when you recycle a view you should explicitly set/reset the image view size again, either based on the image reloaded into it, or if you want them all the same height have a constant for the height.

You might want to also play with some ImageView parameters like adjustViewBounds, or the Fit/Scale settings.

Recently, I ran into some quite different behavior (was EditTextView) between Android 4.0.6 and 4.1.2 (numbers from memory...), and this crap just seems to happen....even betweem quite recent and quite close versions of Android :-(